# Supply assembly version to F# compiler

Tags: f#

Can I supply the assmebly version and assembly informational version to the F# compiler using command line arguments rather than having to generate a file? How?

Comment: Even the `--full-help` command line flag does not reveal any flag that would seem to do this... so my guess is that it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now tracked by https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/3549 and has been accepted at least as a feature request.